# Play Framework 2.5 Logging Issue When Using Compile Time DI

Tags: logging, playframework

I have the following logback.xml definition:

```
<configuration>

  <conversionRule conversionWord="coloredLevel" converterClass="play.api.libs.logback.ColoredLevel" />

  <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
    <file>${application.home:-.}/logs/application.log</file>
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%date [%level] from %logger in %thread - %message%n%xException</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%coloredLevel %logger{15} - %message%n%xException{10}</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <appender name="ASYNCSTDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.AsyncAppender">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
  </appender>

  <logger name="play" level="INFO" />
  <logger name="application" level="INFO" />

  <logger name="com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript" level="OFF" />

  <root level="WARN">
    <appender-ref ref="ASYNCSTDOUT" />
  </root>

</configuration>
```

Here is a sample of how I'm using the Logger to print to the console:

```
class SupervisorActor(globalChannel: GlobalOutputChannel)
  (implicit s: Scheduler) extends Actor {

  private[this] val subscriptions = CompositeCancelable()

  override def preStart = {
    Logger.info(s"starting Supervisor Actor [$self]")
    ....
    ....
}
```

I was expecting to see the '''starting Supervisor Actor [$self]''' statement in my application.log or on the console, but nothing seems to get printed out. Any ideas a to what might be wrong?

Comment: How do you manage your dependencies ? Do you use guice or compile-time DI ?

Comment: I use compile time DI and by the way, I have found out what was wrong and I have posted my answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I use compile time DI, I had to add the following to my Application loader logic:

```
LoggerConfigurator(newContext.environment.classLoader)
  .foreach(_.configure(newContext.environment))
```